# I need cloud Foundry api to view log

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there any api which I can use to read real time application log from pivotal log console? I was reading cloud Foundryclient api but I didn’t find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CF CLI when accessing the logs uses this api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1swqS.png)

I think from api you mean accessing doppler, because this component handles the loggin part
I fired the log command and used verbose option, here i see the http request and response for the same.
Hope it helps